Seek counterexample for local minimum of coordinate-wise convex functions
This question is related to this.
Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is convex in each coordinate (coordinate-wise convex function). Suppose $f$ achieves the global minimum.
In this, @gerw gave a counterexample that $f$ can have two local minimizers, one of which is the global minimizer. In this counterexample, there are three stationary points, and the third is a local maximizer.
@Thomas Ahlecan asked, "can we say that a coordinate wise convex function on $n$
coordinates can only have $n$
distinct minima? " I think the question should be "can have at most $n$ distinct minima" since $f$ can have exactly one local minima e.g. $f = x^2y^2+xy + x^2+y^2+x$ (modified from @gerw's counterexample).
So Question: Can we say that $f$ can have at most $n$ local minima?
I guess the answer is no. I tried to find a counterexample but failed. For example, I modified @gerw's example to $f = x^2y^2 + pxy + x^2+y^2+x$ by choosing different value of $p$, but did not find any counterexample.
